# Android CardView is not showing on activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-cardview

I have a cardview which should show the user a list that comes from my WebApi, I was able to get a list from my Api but I think the problem is because I'm trying to set a adapter inside of `AsyncTask`, my code:

MyAdapter :

```
public class AdapterUserView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterUserView.UserViewHolder> {

private List<UserModelView> mList;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private Context mContext;

public AdapterUserView(Context c,List<UserModelView> l){
    mContext = c;
    mList = l;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_user_card,parent,false);
    AdapterUserView.UserViewHolder mainViewHolder = new AdapterUserView.UserViewHolder(view);
    return mainViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.txtDistrict.setText(mList.get(position).getDistric());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(mList.get(position).getAds_price());
    holder.txtDate.setText(mList.get(position).getAds_date());
    holder.txtImage.setText(mList.get(position).getImage1());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public void addListItem(UserModelView userModelView, int position){
    mList.add(userModelView);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtDistrict;
    public TextView txtPrice;
    public TextView txtDate;
    public TextView txtImage;
    public View view;
    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtDistrict = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.district_card);
        txtPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_card);
        txtDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_card);
        txtImage = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_card);
        view = itemView;
    }
}
```

}

And the "Activity" to receive the data from my Api :

```
public void getAdsUser(final Activity context){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Response = new WebBase().getUserAds(context);
                if(Response.equals("NODATA")){
                    return "NODATA";
                }
                if (Response.equals("EMPTY")){
                    return "EMPTY";
                }
                if (Response.isEmpty()){
                    return "ERROR";
                }
                else {
                    return "OK";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "ERROR";
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            switch (s){
                case "NODATA":
                    GenericAlertDialog.MakeDialog(UserAds.this,R.string.NODATA);
                    break;
                case "ERROR":
                    GenericAlertDialog.MakeDialog(UserAds.this,R.string.Error_Internet);
                    break;
                case "EMPTY":
                    GenericAlertDialog.MakeDialog(UserAds.this,R.string.No_ads_found);
                    break;
                case "OK":
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserModelView>>(){}.getType();
                    List<UserModelView> userModelView = new Gson().fromJson(Response,listType);
                    AdapterUserView adapterUserView = new AdapterUserView(UserAds.this,userModelView);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUserView);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

And i'm trying to set my list Serialized to CardView, and after the onCreate :

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    getAdsUser(UserAds.this);
```

And the Layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecycler"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the LayoutCard :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        android:foregroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/image_card"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="60sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price_card"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/district_card"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/price_card"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_card"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="9.5sp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/price_card"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/price_card"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/district_card"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/district_card"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot from my layout file with cardview :

[image]

and from my phone :

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: where is your cardview in layout?

Comment: inside of layout folder, check the edit post!

Comment: try to put your cardview in your linearlayout

Comment: You mean, my Layout file? Change from Relative to Linear?

Comment: in your layout card Try this <LinearLayout><Cardview>....</CardView></LinearLayout>

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: can u paste screenshot?

Comment: Done, check it out!

Comment: its not a cardview issue you are not getting your data.

Comment: You should `Log.d` the `userModelView.size()` before you set the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

`myadapter.notifyItemInserted()`

I think you must notify on postExecute(). 
Whenever you make changes to the list one must notify as to refresh the View.

Comment: This isn't necessary. `setAdapter` should correctly notify the list to display something (if data is there)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to debug such an issue is, attach a debugger and use breakpoints/logs to find out whether:

- `Response` variable is well initialised before the constructor of the adapter is called
- `userModelView` contains more than one item after response is parsed
- `getItemCount()` in the adapter is being called automatically and it returns a value greater than zero
- `onBindViewHolder` is being called

Steps to fix it would highly vary depending upon where you find the above-mentioned checks to be failing.

I would recommend not to use a field/instance variable for `Response` and rather return it from `doInBackground` to use it in `onPostExecute`. Such instance variables tend to introduce bugs that are difficult to debug/handle/fix.

---

**Edit:**

Try changing:

```
public AdapterUserView(Context c,List<UserModelView> l){
    mContext = c;
    mList = l;
    ....
}
```

to:

```
public AdapterUserView(Context c,List<UserModelView> l){
    mContext = c;

    mList = new ArrayList<>();
    mList.addAll(l);
    ....
}
```

Comment: I notice something, the object `AdapterUserView adapterUserView` is returning zero, but it has data from my WebApi, shoud I use another way to convert it to a List?

Comment: What about `userModelView`? Does it contain any element after it is being initialized with parsed data?

Comment: still not working :/  I was following [this](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106517/cardview-android)

Comment: Does `getItemCount()` returns 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130760/discussion-between-nathiel-paulino-and-kamran-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the reponse from webservice ???

Then  the place where you intialize the recycler view adapter is not right so do it like below

inside onCreate initialize adapter with empty arraylist like  this

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
AdapterUserView adapterUserView = new AdapterUserView(UserAds.this,new ArrayList<UserModelView>();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUserView);
```

Then insed AdapterUserViewClass create method to get your upated list and notifyDataSetchanged like below

```
public setData(List<UserModelView> l){
mList = l;
notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

Now after getting the webservice  reponse,  call your adapter method with your updated list inside onPostExecute method like below

```
case "OK":
                Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserModelView>>(){}.getType();
                List<UserModelView> userModelView = new Gson().fromJson(Response,listType);
                if (userModelView != null && userModelView.size > 0)
                adapterUserView.setData(userModelView);

                break;`
```

Comment: Yes. I'am receiving !

Comment: what is the list size you are getting ?

Comment: the size that i'm getting is 1